# Best way to parse DBXException java

Tags: java, exception, dropbox, dropbox-api

So I recently asked the question of how to handle Dropbox API Exceptions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036981/how-to-deal-with-errors-in-the-dropbox-java-api). I learned that I would have to parse the DBXEception into its [subclasses](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxException.html) which there are many of. Now Thinking about this I am wondering what would be the best way to go about handling this.

Currently I plan on using instanceof and checking like this if I want the program to try again it will return true and the program will try again maybe with a exponential backoff with server request

```
public boolean parseDBX(DbxException e)
    {
        if(e instanceof AccessErrorException) {//handle Error

        }else if (e instanceof DbxApiException) {//handle Error

        }etc
    }
```

It would be called in a catch block like this

```
for(int i =0;;i++) { 
        try {
            ListFolderResult result = client.files().listFolder("/Saves/"+prefName);
            while (true) {
                for (Metadata metadata : result.getEntries()) {
                    System.out.println(metadata.getPathLower());
                    //metadata.
                }

                if (!result.getHasMore()) {
                    break;
                }

                result = client.files().listFolderContinue(result.getCursor());
            }
        } catch (ListFolderErrorException e) {
            createDefFolder();
        } catch (DbxException e) {

            if(codeHandler.parse(e)&&i<10) {
                                continue;
                            }else {
                                log.write("Error 5332490: a problem was encountered while trying to check for the root file"+e.getMessage());
                                throw new IOException();
                            }


        }
        }
```

So My Question is there a way to use a switch statement instead(From what I have found the answer is no), and if not, is there a better way to handle checking for the type of exception.

Comment: Where would you call the `parseDBX()` method? If from within a `catch` block, it would be better to just add a `catch` block specific for each subtype? Maybe some more (code) context would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to avoid "parsing" the exception at all by catching exceptions of the appropriate type:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (AccessErrorException aee) {
    ...
} catch (DbxApiException dae) {
    ...
}
```

In cases when this is not desirable you could associate your own integer ID with each exception type, put it in a `Map`, and use it in your `parse` method to distinguish among subtypes in a `switch`:

```
static Map<Class,Integer> parseId = new HashMap<>();
static {
    parseId.put(AccessErrorException.class, 1);
    parseId.put(DbxApiException.class, 2);
    ...
}
...
public void parseDBX(DbxException e) {
    Integer id = parseId.get(e.getClass());
    if (id != null) {
        switch (id.intValue()) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I plan on using the second one just so I don't have so many catch blocks but, would there be any performance benefit to any one of these options.

Comment: @Austin The first one would use fewer CPU cycles, because the dispatch is done directly by JVM. It wouldn't have a visible impact on performance, because decision to dispatch to a particular chunk of code is a relatively insignificant step in the process of exception handling, especially when exceptions are a result of a network call.